# What is overextending?

Tags: terminology

I've been hearing this term a lot when used in context of scrim matches between teams in TF2, or usually during Highlander sessions.

What does it mean? What does it refer to?

Comment: "To expand or disperse beyond a safe or reasonable limit"

Comment: So what is it context of "tf2"? I'm not asking for a definition in English, I know what it means in English

Comment: Overextending is not a TF2 specific term.  It simply means being too aggressive resulting in making yourself more vulnerable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context of TF2, overextending is commonly used to define a specific mistake in attack/defense maps. On defense, a team "overextends" when they repel an initial offensive wave and proceed to *extend* as far as they can, hoping to push the offense all the way to their base and begin a spawn camp, which generally wins games.

However, given that this usually occurs when the defense is on their last capture point, their last point is now vulnerable to any enterprising Spy or Scout. Any offensive player that recognizes an potential overextension will try to hide and ride out the defensive push-back, then proceed to capture the now un-defended point.

Answer (score 1):

Individually, one can also overextend in a match on TF2 (or any team-based game).

Typically on a team-based game, teammates launch their assault/defense as a front, with various different characters/classes at different parts of the front, some closer to the enemy, some further behind, some even extending into the enemy's own front and behind them.

Overextending, on an individual basis, is when a person goes further than they should in their push, usually into the thick of the enemy's own front where they become overwhelmed by surrounding enemies.